# Get Siri Remote orientation (or get notifications of change?)

Tags: tvos, orientation-changes, apple-tv, siri-remote

I'm been searching for a way to check the Siri Remote's current orientation or to register for Siri Remote orientation changes, but I haven't found anything yet. Is it possible to do this (without resorting to interpreting the raw gravity data)?

I've *have* found out how to disable auto-orientation changes with "allowsRotation" on "microGamepad". Which is pretty cool!

Comment: I was just at an Apple TV tech talk yesterday that was hosted by the Apple TV team @ Apple. They did mention detecting orientation of the remote, though I don't remember if they showed any code.

Comment: Oh man, I was at the tech talk in Austin. I _thought_ they said something about detecting orientation too. I remember a slide saying something about "portrait, landscape, and landscape flipped". But I can't find any references to it online.

Comment: Closest thing I can find is: [Using the Apple TV Remote as a Game Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwithGameControllers.html). *The remote can be used in either a portrait or landscape orientation. When you create your app, you decide whether the profile object flips the input data automatically when the user changes the remote orientation.*

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see an API either, however as you mentioned, you can poll for the gravity data, and I just wanted to post that code here in case some find it useful. You can modify this to your own need, such as detecting last orientation and comparing it to current if you want a callback of the change.

```
    //**************************************************************
    // Update loop portion to UIViewController
    //**************************************************************
    @property (strong) CADisplayLink *updateLoopTimer;
    self.updateLoopTimer = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateRefreshRate:)];
    [self.updateLoopTimer addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    -(void)updateRefreshRate:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
    {
        CFTimeInterval deltaTime = displayLink.duration * displayLink.frameInterval;
        [self update:(float)deltaTime];
    }

 //******************************************************
// Update loop
//******************************************************
-(void)update:(float)dt
{
#ifdef TV
    //***************************************
    // Detect button presses
    //***************************************
    //self.gameControler = [[GCController controllers] firstObject];
    if( self.gameController != nil )
    {
        GCMicroGamepad* microPad = self.gameController.microGamepad;
        if ( microPad != nil )
        {
            GCMotion *motion = self.gameController.motion;
            GCControllerDirectionPad *dpad = microPad.dpad;

            if( motion != nil )
            {
                GCAcceleration accelVector = motion.gravity;
                if( fabs(accelVector.x) > fabs(accelVector.y) )
                {
                    NSLog(@"Sideways");
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"Upright");
                }

            }
        }
    }
#endif
}
```